# Imprimir todos resultados de um vetor com determinado valor

Tags: c, loop, array

Estou iniciando os estudos em C. Tenho uma dúvida de como percorrer um vetor procurando nele um valor e imprimir mostrando com `printf` todos os valores encontrados.

O programa que estou fazendo: http://pastebin.com/X2tev5is

No programa acima, seria o case 5, onde quero mostrar todos funcionários pelo código do cargo.
Obrigado antemão

Comment: Qual é o problema mesmo?

Comment: Pelo meu código, quando aperto para ele Exibir as informacoes dos funcionarios por cargo, ele mostra apenas um funcionário. Eu quero fazer que mostre todos os funcionários com determinado cargo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia seguir essa lógica:

```
case 5:
     //MOSTRA POR CARGO
     printf("Digite o codigo do cargo:\n");
     printf("\n 100\tEngenheiro\n 200\tMestre de Obras\n\300\tPedreiro\n 400\tEstagiario\n");

     scanf("%i", &pesquisa);
     ok = 0;
     // Avisa se o cargo pesquisado nao existe
     if ((pesquisa != 100) && (pesquisa != 200) && (pesquisa != 300) (pesquisa != 400)){
        printf("Pesquisa invalida!");
     }
     else {
        // Loop para percorrer o vetor cargo e verificar a pesquisa
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++) {
           if(pesquisa==cargo[j]) {
              ok = 1;
              printf("\n***********************************\n");
              printf("Funcionario numero %i\n", j);
              printf("Matricula %i\n", matricula[j]);
              printf("Cargo:%i\n", cargo[j]);
              printf("Salario: $ %.2f\n", saldo[j]);
           }
        }
     }

     // Se nao encontrar nenhum funcionario pela pesquisa
     if (ok == 0){
        printf("Sem resultado!\n");
     }
break;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ele continua mostrando somente 1 funcionario. Eu queria que ao cadastrar 2 funcionarios com código 100 (cargo), a função mostrasse os 2 funcionários cadastrados com o código 100

Comment: Estranho testei hoje de manhã e estava funcionando, daqui a pouco eu testo novamente.

Comment: Perdão, deu certo. Foi um erro meu, verifiquei novamente aqui. Mt obrigado